# ReferenceError: document is not defined when refresh nextjs page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering

i am trying to create a simple UI library using react for Nextjs 9.4, here what i am doing

```
// input.js in React UI Lib

import React from "react";
import styled from "./input.module.scss";

const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <>
    {props.label && <label className={styled.label}>{props.label}</label>}
    <input className={styled.input} {...props} ref={ref} />
  </>
));

export default Input;
```

and made an index to export all modules for simplicity

```
// app.js the index file for the lib

import PrimaryButton from "./components/button/primaryButton";
import TextInput from "./components/input/input";
import PasswordInput from "./components/passwordInput/password";
import CheckBox from "./components/checkbox/checkbox";

export {
  PrimaryButton,
  TextInput,
  PasswordInput,
  CheckBox
};
```

also here is my webpack config to build for SSR Next

```
const path = require("path");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const CSSLoader = {
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
    modules: "global",
    importLoaders: 2,
    sourceMap: false,
  },
};

const CSSModlueLoader = {
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
    modules: true,
    importLoaders: 2,
    sourceMap: false,
  },
};

const PostCSSLoader = {
  loader: "postcss-loader",
  options: {
    ident: "postcss",
    sourceMap: false,
    plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
  },
};

const SassLoader = {
  loader: "sass-loader",
  options: {
    // Prefer `dart-sass`
    implementation: require("sass"),
  },
};

module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[id].js",
    publicPath: "",
    library: "",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.module\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i],
        use: ["style-loader", CSSLoader, PostCSSLoader, SassLoader],
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["style-loader", CSSModlueLoader, PostCSSLoader, SassLoader],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&name=img/[name].[ext]",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

1-i build

2-publush on npm

3-import in Nextjs

then everything works well , but the problem is when i try to refresh (F5) the page during development i get the error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

how can i fix that ?

Comment: you have not access window || document during SSR so try to prevent rendering during this time like , `typeof window !=== 'undefined' ? <Component /> : null`

Comment: @Mashiro i have changed component to `typeof window !== 'undefined' ? <>
    {props.label && <label className={styled.label}>{props.label}</label>}
    <input className={styled.input} {...props} ref={ref} />
  </> : null`, still same error

Comment: can u provide a link to your bundled file

Comment: i figured out why it occurs check answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. try to render component only in client side you can do with:

   `typeof window !== 'undefined' ? <Component /> : null`
2. you are using `style-loader` in your webpack config, it will [inject styles](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) into head using `document.createElement` that is not availabe in SSR, you can choose other options like [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin)

Comment: `typeof window !== 'undefined' && <Component /> ` works too

Answer (score 1):

```
const Example = dynamic( () => import('example'), { ssr: false } )
```

https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour/issues/130

Answer (score 1):

try to check component in client side rendering ex:

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
isBrowser ? <Component/> : null;
```

another option is try to render using ssr false:

```
const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
() => import('../components/hello3'),
{ ssr: false }
)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You may not always want to include a module on server-side. For example, when the module includes a library that only works in the browser.

Take a look at the following example:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
() => import('../components/hello3'),
{ ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
return (
<div>
  <Header />
  <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
  <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
</div>
 )
}

export default Home
```